# How do instantiate a class when the class name is only available at runtime

Tags: javascript

The usual situation for instantiation is `new MyClass(arg1)`.

How do I code the situation when `MyClass` is a variable whose value is only available at runtime?

Answer (score 6):

All globals are properties of the global object.
You can get object properties by name using indexer notation:

```
new global[someString]();
```

In a browser, the global object is `window`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're saying is that you have `"MyClass"` as a string-variable in JavaScript, you can do it  with `Eval`:

```
var yourvar = "MyClass";
eval("new " + yourvar + "();");
```

Note: eval can be dangerous and should be avoided when possible. In this case it would work, but it's not the recommended method. If you can show us your use case, we could maybe give you a better, safer solution.

Comment: The name of the class is passed into a function as a function argument say class1.

eval('var c = new' + class1 ' + ();' ;